# How find this $xyz|(xy-1)(xz-1)(yz-1)$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

let $x,y,z$ be postive integers and  $x\neq y\neq z$ such
$$xyz|(xy-1)(xz-1)(yz-1)$$
Find all $x,y,z$,

my try:
$$(xy-1)(yz-1)(xz-1)=x^2y^2z^2-xyz(x+y+z)+(xy+yz+xz)-1$$
then 
$$\dfrac{(xy-1)(yz-1)(xz-1)}{xyz}=xyz-(x+y+z)+\dfrac{xy+zy+xz-1}{xyz}$$
so
$$\dfrac{xy+yz+xz-1}{xyz}\in N$$
Then I can't get any further

I found $(x,y,z)=(2,3,5),(2,5,3),(3,2,5),(3,5,2),(5,2,3),(5,3,2)$such it, I don't know/have any other,

also How to prove it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculation is a useful beginning. You have concluded that $xyz$ divides $xy+yz+zx-1$. Let us suppose that $x\gt y\gt z$. Note that $xy+yz+zx-1\lt 3xy$. So $z=1$ or $z=2$. But it cannot be $1$.

We have reached the equation $xy+2(x+y)-1=2xy$. The rest is left to you.